# jstl foreach won't iterate a list

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

I want to iterate a list which is passed to my `jsp` via `request` scope.

This is the code I tried :

```
<c:forEach items="${param.evaluateurs}" var="evaluateur">
     <c:out value="${evaluateur.lastname}"></c:out> <c:out value="${evaluateur.fistname}"</c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

but when I run my `jsp` I only see one entry, so I guess that it didn't iterate the list.

but when I use `for loop` it works :

```
<%
java.util.List<emaeval.statistic.doa.Users> evaluateurs = 
        (java.util.List<emaeval.statistic.doa.Users>) request.getAttribute("evaluateurs");
for(emaeval.statistic.doa.Users evaluateur : evaluateurs) {
 %> 

<%= evaluateur.getFirstname() %> <%= evaluateur.getLastname() %> 

<% } %>
```

What is wrong with the jstl method ?

Comment: Are you missing `>` in `<c:out value="${evaluateur.fistname}"` or is it just an copy-paste error?

Comment: yes it's just a copy-past error

Answer (score 0):

In `jstl` `param` is equivalent to `request.getParameter`. As you have to access it from the `request` you have to iterate like below

```
<c:forEach items="${evaluateurs}" var="evaluateur">
     <c:out value="${evaluateur.lastname}"></c:out> <c:out value="${evaluateur.fistname}"</c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the *evaluateurs* is not sent as request *parameter*, but request *attribute* to the JSP. So therefore you have to take it from the proper place (**not** from *parameter map*).

Instead of using `"${param.evaluateurs}"` use simply `"${evaluateurs}"`.